# How to make nickname for Heroku --app values

Tags: heroku, heroku-toolbelt

my Heroku git repo has two apps.  It's configured using [fork](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/fork-app)

So I can deploy to diff servers like this:

    `git push production master
    git push stage dev:master`

And check logs/etc using the --app parameter:

    `heroku logs --app superlongappname-stage
    heroku logs --app superlongappname`

Cool.  But typing 'superlongappname-stage' every time I want to work with the staging server is a pain in the ass.

Is there a way to use 'stage' instead of 'superlongappname-stage'? E.g.

    `heroku logs --app stage
    heroku logs --app production`

or better yet have stage be the default:

    `heroku logs
    heroku logs --app production`

Thanks!

Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about just renaming your apps? Heroku documentation on it [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/renaming-apps).

Basically, from your CLI:

```
heroku apps:rename stage --app superlongappname-stage
heroku apps:rename production --app superlongappname
```

Note that you'll probably need to use something other than a simple 'stage' or 'production', as it needs to be a unique appname (`stage.heroku.com`), and I'm guessing stage and production are already taken. The point remains that you can change it to something easy.

Also, remember to update your git remotes. From your git checkout directory:

```
git remote rm heroku
heroku git:remote -a stage
```

Comment: Basically, it's not possible as I want to do it.